# Do symbolic links work both directions?

Tags: windows, macos, dropbox, symbolic-link

I created a symbolic link between a folder on my local computer and DropBox.  If I modify files in the linked folder on Dropbox from another computer, will those new/modified files also be pushed into the linked folder on the local computer?

Comment: Please explain your question. A symbolic link to a target directory is not itself a directory, and therefore has no contents. It is just a pointer to another location. It makes no sense to speak of a file being "pushed" into a symbolic link.

Comment: I use "pushed" in context of dropbox. I'll try to think of a better term. The pointer is pointing to a directory on the first local machine.  Therefore dropbox uploads the directory pointed to.  I am asking If I were to modify a file on dropbox in a second machine while the first is off, will those modified files be updated on the first machine when it is powered on and connects with dropbox.

Comment: And if this is so, that would mean the pointer is doubly linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a symbolic link is a pointer to another location. This means that any changes you make are in fact updating at the target location.